# TypeScript: call prototype method on any object - shorter syntax?

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript (not Java, C# or Objecive-C), is there a shorter syntax for the following code (similar to ::bind operator)?

```
const company = { rating: 5 }
Company.prototype.getRating.call(company) // <----- NEED A SHORTER SYNTAX
```

given:

./Company.ts

```
class Company {
  rating: string;

  getRating() {
    return this.rating + " stars";
  }
}
```

Is there an alternate shorter syntax I can tell people to follow or should I ask them to do long .prototype. syntax only?

Something like this:

```
((Company)company).getRating(); // or (company as Company).getRating();
```

Best would be:

```
(company:Company).getRating();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `company` object is not an instance of `Company`, it's just an object literal. You could do one of several things:

Use `Object.assign` to assign the properties to an instance of `Company`:

```
const company = Object.assign(new Company(), { rating: 5 })
company.getRating();
```

Create a constructor that calls `Object.assign`:

```
class Company {
    rating: number;
    constructor(data: Partial<Company>){
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
    getRating() {
      return this.rating + " stars";
    }
  }

const company = new Company({ rating: 5 });
company.getRating();
```

Or you can use a function that changes the prototype for the object (although this may cause problems if `Company` has a constructor as the constructor will not get executed for objects that go through `cast`, also changing the `__proto__` is slow)  :

```
function cast<T>(obj, type: { new(...args): T }): T {
    obj.__proto__ = type.prototype;
    return obj;
}
const company = cast({ rating: 5 }, Company);
company.getRating();
```

Comment: So there isn't a shorter syntax so far.  Object.assign(new Company, company) is still slower than .prototype. computationally and still long :)  I like the second approach constructor(data: Partial<Company>){ The third one may be useful when an absolute copying of methods to the object is required, but may not recommend it. Good insights.  Question is still about shorter syntax in TypeScript. May be an issue/feature request I should add in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues

Comment: @MohammedSheriff not shorter for a single call, but if you want to call several methods it is shorter, and more readable

Comment: Answer taken for Object.assign(new Company, obj) similar to casting syntax from other langs and requires no modification to existing classes. Second approach is great for shorter syntax in usage and for mentioning constructor Partial support for object literal converts. Best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The point for TypeScript is not to write things short, but to improve readability, enable IDEs, and write scaleable code.
The compiled js code will be longer than vanilla js anyway, so comparing which line is shorter doesn't make sense.

This should work:

```
const company = new Company(); 
company.rating = 5; 
company.ratingString;
```

In your class:

```
class Company {
  rating: number;

  get ratingString() {
    return this.rating + " stars";
  }
}
```

Note:
`rating` in the class is a string, but in company object is number, which doesn't match up.